# Rotate an image around its center in canvas

Tags: javascript, image, animation, rotation, html5-canvas

I'm trying to do my first image animation on canvas. I want the image to rotate but something is not correct in my code. Any ideas?  This is all in a jquery document ready:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('logobg1');  
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var img = new Image();   // Create new Image object
    img.src = 'images/containerbg.png'; // Set source path // set img src

    img.onload = function(){ // when image loads
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
        setInterval(function() {
            ctx.save();
            ctx.clearRect(-ctx.canvas.width/2, -ctx.canvas.height/2, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
            ctx.translate(ctx.canvas.width/2, ctx.canvas.height/2); // set canvas context to center
            ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * 0.5); // 1/2 a degree
            ctx.restore();
        }, 16);
    }
```

Comment: Try 'Visual-js game engine' , https://jsfiddle.net/zlatnaspirala/y16s2krh/  planetarium in 5 minute

Comment: Anyone who doesn't understand what is  going on, I highly recommend this video on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=TBXjWsR7XDA

Answer (score 19, accepted):

just change the order of your code, i.e.,

```
ctx.rotate(...);

ctx.drawImage(...);
```

### See a working example **http://jsbin.com/owuyiq/**

```
$(function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('logobg1');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var img = new Image();

    var ang = 0; //angle
    var fps = 1000 / 25; //number of frames per sec
    img.onload = function () { //on image load do the following stuff
        canvas.width = this.width << 1; //double the canvas width
        canvas.height = this.height << 1; //double the canvas height
        var cache = this; //cache the local copy of image element for future reference
        setInterval(function () {
            ctx.save(); //saves the state of canvas
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //clear the canvas
            ctx.translate(cache.width, cache.height); //let's translate
            ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * (ang += 5)); //increment the angle and rotate the image 
            ctx.drawImage(img, -cache.width / 2, -cache.height / 2, cache.width, cache.height); //draw the image ;)
            ctx.restore(); //restore the state of canvas
        }, fps);
    };

    img.src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z97wf.jpg?s=128'; //img
});
```

Comment: you need to vary the rotation angle.., i.e, `ctx.rotate(Math.PI /180 * angle)`. for every loop(setInterval) increment the `angle` value...

Comment: ok it rotates but it doesn't rotate around the center rather than the top left.

Comment: You need to add two additional parameters to rotate which are the X and Y of the coordinates to rotate around on. In this case you will have to use the center X and center Y coordinates of your object.

Comment: Modified the example above to work when your canvas has a fixed size (not based on your image size): [jsbin.com/suwovibove/](http://jsbin.com/suwovibove/edit?js,output). I will add it as answer in case that link vanishes.

Answer (score 10):

Based on the comments above, but a bit more simple and in vanilla. This one worked for me perfectly.
Of course you should use clearRect in order to erase the canvas on each rendering.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('#my-canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
var ang = 0

function rotateAndRenderImg() {
    var img = document.querySelector('img')
    ctx.save()
    var pos = {x: desiredRenderPosX, y: desiredRenderPosY}
    ctx.translate(pos.x ,pos.y)    
    ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * (ang += 5))
    ctx.drawImage(img, -img.width / 2, -img.height / 2, img.width, img.height)
    ctx.restore()
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Based in the accepted answer, this example, allows you to use a fixed canvas size (and not in relation to the image size):

```js
 $(function() {
 
        var canvas = document.getElementById('logobg1');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var img = new Image();
    
        var ang = 0; //angle
        var fps = 1000 / 25; //number of frames per sec
        img.onload = function () { //on image load do the following stuff
            canvas.width = 500; //Any width
            canvas.height = 500; //Any height
            var cache = this; //cache the local copy of image element for future reference
            var iw = cache.width;
            var ih = cache.height;
            setInterval(function () {
                ctx.save(); //saves the state of canvas
                ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); //clear the canvas
                ctx.translate(canvas.width/2, canvas.height/2); //let's translate
                ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * (ang += 5)); //increment the angle and rotate the image 
                ctx.translate(-(canvas.width/2), -(canvas.height/2)); //let's translate
                ctx.drawImage(img, canvas.width/2 - iw/2, canvas.height/2 - ih/2, iw, ih); //draw the image ;)
                ctx.restore(); //restore the state of canvas
            }, fps);
        };
        
        img.src = 'https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300'; //img
 
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="logobg1" > test canvas <canvas>
```

Working example: [jsbin.com/suwovibove/](http://jsbin.com/suwovibove/edit?html,js,output)

Note: try removing `ctx.save` and `ctx.restore` for a cool spin.

Comment: Thanks for the example, Just for clarification, I would change the name of the variable `fps` because it is an interval.