# How to rotate an image on HTML5 canvas when the right and left arrow keys are pressed

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I need help trying to rotate the rectangle that I have drawn on the canvas. I would like the top of the rectangle to pivot either to the right or left once I press on the arrow keys on my keyboard. This is my code so far:

[image: Canvas]

HTML:

```
  <body >
    <div id="canvas-container">
      <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
```

CSS:

```
canvas {
   display: inline;
}
```

Javascript:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    drawBorder();
});

var canvas;
var context;
var size;

drawRectangle();
drawHalfCircle();

function drawBorder() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    size = {
        x: canvas.width,
        y: canvas.height
    };
    //have to set colors etc befor it is drawn
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    //takes 4 parameters
    context.strokeRect(0, 0, size.x, size.y);
}

function drawRectangle() {
    var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.rect(246, 290, 8, 80);
    ctx.stroke();
}

function drawHalfCircle(){
    var c= document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(250,579,308,1.2*Math.PI, 1.8*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();
}
```

Comment: Perhaps have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422293/rotate-an-image-around-its-center-in-canvas :) or am i missing apart of the question

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5597060/detecting-arrow-key-presses-in-javascript for keypressing :)

Comment: @Spaceman Thanks for the references, but I already read over both of those posts and still not able to figure it out

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 canvas - rotate object without moving coordinates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17125632/html5-canvas-rotate-object-without-moving-coordinates)

Comment: @Kaiido its a possible duplicate of many things but I never know how to deal with dups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have mocked something up is this along the correct lines of what you are wanting.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    drawBorder();
});

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var size;
var angle = 0;

setInterval(function () {
    context.save(); 
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); 

    drawBorder();
    drawHalfCircle();
    drawRectangle();

    context.restore(); 
 }, 100);

function drawBorder() {
    size = {
        x: canvas.width,
        y: canvas.height
    };

    //have to set colors etc befor it is drawn
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    //takes 4 parameters
    context.strokeRect(0, 0, size.x, size.y);
}

function drawRectangle() {
    context.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * (angle));
    context.rect(246, 290, 8, 80);
    context.stroke();
}

function drawHalfCircle(){
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(250,579,308,1.2*Math.PI, 1.8*Math.PI);
    context.stroke();
}

document.onkeydown = function(e) {
    var event = window.event ? window.event : e;

    if (e.keyCode == '37') {
       angle += 5;
    }
    else if (e.keyCode == '39') {
       angle -= 5;
    }
}
```

Basically set an interval and redraw (ie frames like in a movie) and rotate via a variable.

See a demo here
https://jsbin.com/qititacazu/edit?js,output

If you want to translate it so it will rotate around a different point do something like this.

```
context.translate(246, 290); 
context.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * (angle));
context.rect(-4, 0, 4, 80);
```

Comment: If you want an explanation on any part i can expand on it.

Comment: very close! How do you switch it so it rotate from the bottom of the rectangle verses the top?

Comment: context.translate(246, 290);  Set the translate to the point you want to rotate around then draw the rectangle points then rotate

Comment: No worries, If that the correct answer glad I could help.