# Image disappears when clicking button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why does the image disappear when I click button  Rotate Anti-clockwise and Rotate clock-clockwise?

https://plnkr.co/edit/YFFx7oWnH1V2ppmtZWxW?p=preview

```
function drawImage() {
     clear();
    element.save();
    element.scale(currentScale, currentScale);
    element.rotate(currentAngle * Math.PI / 180);
    element.drawImage(image, canvas.width/2/currentScale - image.width/2, canvas.height/2/currentScale - image.height/2);
    element.restore();
}
```

any update ?

Comment: Change to type="button"

Comment: It seems like you're not rotating image at its center, try to rotate it in that way. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422293/rotate-an-image-around-its-center-in-canvas)

Comment: @PankajParkar can you please change on my pluker

Answer (score 0):

check the below link it is working

`click this link` http://jsfiddle.net/sreenivas644/CPKmN/576

Comment: @sreenvias this is not I am looking for ..sorry

Comment: please remove this anserr