# Why is this just rotating and not moving to the right?

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following web page:

```js
var box_x = 30;
var box_y = 30;
var box_width = 30;
var box_height = 30;
var box_direction = 20; // Degrees clockwise

function draw_box() {
  var c = document.getElementById("area");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
  ctx.rotate(box_direction * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.fillRect(box_x, box_y, 100, 50);
  box_x += 2;
}

setInterval(draw_box, 1000);
```

```html
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<canvas id="area" width="500px" height="500px" style="border: 1px solid #0000aa" />
</canvas>
```

Why is the box not just moving to the right?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what [`rotate`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate) does. It _is_ moving to the right. You just keep changing where “right” is.

Comment: Do you want the box to just move towards right?  Also rotation is required or not? and what is box_direction then?

Comment: You are calling `rotate()`, why do you expect it to move to the right?

Comment: Box direction is the angle of the box

Comment: `box_x += 2;` Though that would move the box

Comment: You rotate from the top left corner, it does not rotate from the center. Searching for "canvas rotate from center" should give you plenty of answers

Comment: I think you need to make sure you rotate around the center of your rectangle using [ctx.translate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4422293/rotate-an-image-around-its-center-in-canvas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ctx.rotate rotates the entire canvas from the top left corner, so you should first use ctx.translate to move the top left corner to the pivot (which is the box's
top left corner) and then do the same but in reverse so you reset the rotation and translation of the canvas

```js
var box_x = 30;
var box_y = 30;
var box_width = 30;
var box_height = 30;
var box_direction = 20; // Degrees clockwise

function draw_box() {
  var c = document.getElementById("area");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

  ctx.translate(box_x, box_y);
  ctx.rotate(box_direction * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 50);
  ctx.rotate(-box_direction * Math.PI / 180);
  ctx.translate(-box_x, -box_y);

  box_x += 2;
}

setInterval(draw_box, 1000);
```

```html
<h1>Welcome</h1>
<canvas id="area" width="500px" height="500px" style="border: 1px solid #0000aa" />
</canvas>
```